# Searching for multiple matches on one line using Grep and Regex

Tags: regex, command-line, grep

I'm trying to use `Grep` with `wc -l` to print out the number of words in a text file that have 3 or more vowels in a row.

Right now, I'm inputting:

```
grep -i -E '<\.*[aeiou]{3}.*\>' file.txt | wc -l
```

but this is not returning the correct number of words, because on some lines there are multiple words that have 3 vowels in a row.

if file.txt contains this :

```
beautiful courteous 
beautiful 
courteous
```

my desired output would be 4, rather than 3, and currently I'm only able to get 3.

I've been looking online for a while for a solution but I just can't seem to figure it out. Can anyone assist?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get each matching word on a separate line, use the `-o` option:

```
$ grep -iEo '[[:alnum:]]*[aeiou]{3}[[:alnum:]]*' file.txt
beautiful
courteous
beautiful
courteous
$ grep -iEo '[[:alnum:]]*[aeiou]{3}[[:alnum:]]*' file.txt | wc -l
4
```

`[[:alnum:]]*[aeiou]{3}[[:alnum:]]*` matches words with three consecutive vowels.  `-o` assures that each word is on a separate line.

If you want to be stricter about the definition of a word, you may want instead to use `[[:alpha:]]*[aeiou]{3}[[:alpha:]]*`.

#### Documentation

From `man grep`:

> **-o, --only-matching**
>    Print only the matched (non-empty)
>   parts of a matching line, with each such part on a separate output
>   line.

#### Discussion

Consider:

```
\<.*[aeiou]{3}.*\>'
```

In the above, note that `.` matches *any* character and `.*` is greedy: it matches the longest possible match.  Thus, `\<.*[aeiou]{3}` will match from the beginning of the first word on a line to the last occurrence on the line of three vowels in a row.  The final `.*\>` will match from there to the end of the last word on the line.  This is not what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You should do it in 2 steps...

First you split the file into words:

```
tr -s '[[:punct:][:space:]]' '\n' < file.txt > wordsFile.txt
```

and then you count the matching words:

```
grep -i -E '.*[aeiou]{3}.*' wordsFile.txt | wc -l
```